# How could I read information from SIM card in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I mean in programming way. Like read contact details through SIM card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing the SIM card isn't possible, at least through the SDK (and therefore not publishable on the app store).

If you want to get at the address book though, there's an API for that.

Check out

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Framework/_index.html