# Get Sim identification no / serial no from the iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I would like to know is it possible to get the Sim identification no (not mobile no) from the iPhone programmatically.

Thanks for anyy help

Comment: Pretty sure this information is not exposed for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How could I read information from SIM card in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700833/how-could-i-read-information-from-sim-card-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wel yes you can get them, but not via the official API. If you app needs to be in the AppStore then this is not possible.